# How to redirect stdout and stderr output from command prompt ONLY when there is an error?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, stdout, stderr, file-rename

I have a batch file (.cmd file) with millions of rename commands on each line. Each line is a UNC path from a database with a new name based on the extension listed in the table. Anyhow, I am ware that if I add 2>&1 then I can get the stderr and stdout, therefore, I can identify which files were not present in the storage. But since there are millions of files, I would prefer if we only logged the stdout and stderr together ONLY if a specific file was not found. In other words log ONLY when there was an error while running the command. I am running this on Windows 7.

```
REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\84 84.TIF
REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\85 85.TIF
REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\86 86.TIF
REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\87 87.TIF
REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\88 88.TIF
```

So lets say that if file 88.TIF is not present in the storage, then I will get an error saying: 
"REN \nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\88 88.TIF
The system cannot find the file specified."

Since I could have millions of command lines in each batch file, I just need to log the ones where I see the error with the command included as shown in the sample error above.

Comment: You should provide examples and a code fragment...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot selectively redirect both stderr and stdout only when an error occurs. But you don't need to do that. You are in a position to know what file you attempted to delete, so all you need is the ability to detect an error, and then write whatever message you want.

I would restructure your code to be something like:

```
@echo off
call :REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\84 84.TIF
call :REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\85 85.TIF
call :REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\86 86.TIF
call :REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\87 87.TIF
call :REN \\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\88 88.TIF
exit /b

:ren
>>error.log 2>&1 (ren %1 %2 || (
  REN %1 %2 FAILED
  echo(
)
exit /b
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
@echo off
>error.log 2>&1 (
  for %%F in (
    "\\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\84|84.TIF"
    "\\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\85|85.TIF"
    "\\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\86|86.TIF"
    "\\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\87|87.TIF"
    "\\nas0i08lv\DATA\HPFArchive\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch048\17\88|88.TIF"
  ) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%A in (%%F) do (
    ren "%%A" "%%B" || (
      echo REN "%%A" "%%B" FAILED
      echo(
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: thank you sir for the suggestion. However, the former code design suggested by you does not work at all. It neither renames the target test file nor does it create a log. The latter code design does not rename the file, instead it errors out where it should not. Error given: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
REN "REN C:\Users\ahmedamm\Desktop\HPF_Test\Image" "Image.TIF" FAILED". FYI I have not worked with batch programming in the past.